# Update loop does not show last day in month before rolling over

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I have the following C# script acting as a "Time Manager" within Unity:

```
void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        SetCurrentDay(currentDate.day.day++);


        if (currentDate.day.day >= currentDate.month.maxDays)
        {
            SetCurrentDay(0);
            SetCurrentMonth(currentDate.month.month++);
        }

        timer = minuteToRealTime;
    }
}
```

So far, I have this looping correctly. However, lets take January for example. I have this loop through 01 Jan, Year 1.

It then goes through each one until we hit 30 Jan, Year 1. I would then expect it to show 31 (as this is the `maxDays` within the month and thus show 31 Jan, Year 1. However it doesn't. Instead it "rolls over" to February, showing 01 Feb, Year 1.

If I then allow it to go to the end of February, it cuts off the 28th and goes to the 1st of March and so on.

I'm feeling a little stupid as I feel this is an easy task to get right, however I'm calling blanks on how to actually get it to show the final day before rolling over.

How could this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is setting the day to 31ste on `SetCurrentDay(currentDate.day.day++);`
Than in the next line you check is it is equal to or bigger than the max day. in you `if`
It is so it will go to day 0.

if you change the if to only check in bigger than it will rollover a day later.
`if (currentDate.day.day > currentDate.month.maxDays)`

Edit:

So if that gives a argument out of range means that it is not allowed to go to dat 32. You could try this:

```
void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        if (currentDate.day.day >= currentDate.month.maxDays)
        {
            SetCurrentDay(0);
            SetCurrentMonth(currentDate.month.month++);
        }
        else
        {           
            SetCurrentDay(currentDate.day.day++);
        }

        timer = minuteToRealTime;
    }
}
```

So we check if the day is the max day of the month than it rolles over to the next month, else we add a day.

Comment: Instead of rolling over on the last day, it goes into an ```ArgumentOutOfRangeException``` so we're almost there